# C++11 Struct definition with atomic attribute

Tags: c++11, struct, thread-safety, atomic, definition

In C++11 I have a struct with lots of attributes like so:

```
#include <atomic>
struct Foo {
  int x;
  int y;
  // ...
  // LOTS of primitive type attributes, followed by...
  // ...
  std::atomic_bool bar;
}
```

And I'd like to define an instance like so:

```
bool bar_value = true;
Foo my_foo = {/*attribute values*/, bar_value};
```

However, the atomic_bool is throwing a "use of deleted function" error because I think copy constructing is not allowed on atomics.  Is there any way around this, short of writing out a constructor or assigning each value individually?

It just seems inconvenient to have to treat this otherwise relatively banal struct in a special way just because one of its many attributes is a special case.

**Updates:**

- Any takers?  I've been looking around, but there doesn't seem to be any straightforward way to resolve this.

Comment: You can write your own copy constructor or you could try something like this: Define struct Foo without atomics, then define FooExtended that inherits from Foo and adds atomics. Then define copy constructor in FooExtended with list initialization for atomics, after initialization cast argument to Foo class and pass it to base class copy constructor. It's a solution with least work I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try wrapping the initialization of the atomic_bool in its own initializer list.  It worked for me in g++ [4.7](http://ideone.com/91OjWe).

```
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>

struct Foo
{
    int x;
    int y;
    std::atomic_bool bar;
};

int main(int, char**)
{
    Foo f1 = {1, 2, {true}};
    Foo f2 = {3, 4, {false}};

    std::cout << "f1 - " << f1.x << " " << f1.y << " "
              << (f1.bar.load()?"true":"false") << std::endl;
    std::cout << "f2 - " << f2.x << " " << f2.y << " "
              << (f2.bar.load()?"true":"false") << std::endl;
}
```

I got the following output:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -o test && ./test
f1 - 1 2 true
f2 - 3 4 false
```

Comment: Wow, thanks, that works pretty well!  Do you know why that is?  In any case, that makes my life a lot easier, thanks again!